# Accessing members of items in a JSONArray with Java

Tags: java, json, arrays

I'm just getting started with using json with java.  I'm not sure how to access string values within a JSONArray. For instance, my json looks like this:

```
{
  "locations": {
    "record": [
      {
        "id": 8817,
        "loc": "NEW YORK CITY"
      },
      {
        "id": 2873,
        "loc": "UNITED STATES"
      },
      {
        "id": 1501
        "loc": "NEW YORK STATE"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

my code:

```
JSONObject req = new JSONObject(join(loadStrings(data.json),""));
JSONObject locs = req.getJSONObject("locations");
JSONArray recs = locs.getJSONArray("record");
```

I have access to the "record" JSONArray at this point, but am unsure as to how I'd get the "id" and "loc" values within a for loop.  Sorry if this description isn't too clear, I'm a bit new to programming.

Comment: Another thing (probably you found it)- you have missed a comma after third id value. It's good to always use some parser, for example http://json.parser.online.fr/

Answer (score 244, accepted):

Have you tried using [JSONArray.getJSONObject(int)](http://json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#getJSONObject(int)), and [JSONArray.length()](http://json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#length()) to create your for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < recs.length(); ++i) {
    JSONObject rec = recs.getJSONObject(i);
    int id = rec.getInt("id");
    String loc = rec.getString("loc");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I don't get this. If we can get `id` with a sinple `getInt` like how we get the value of a hashmap by specifying the key, then why do we have to iterate with a for loop? Doesn't iteration with the loop make the `id` get assigned to `int id` multiple times?

Comment: For more complex JSON found this nice solution per https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/json/java-json-parser-example/

Comment: How would this work if I know the ID but need the matching loc?

Comment: Both of these links are broken

Answer (score 5):

An [org.json.JSONArray](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html) is not iterable.
Here's how I process elements in a [net.sf.json.JSONArray](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/JSONArray.html):

```
    JSONArray lineItems = jsonObject.getJSONArray("lineItems");
    for (Object o : lineItems) {
        JSONObject jsonLineItem = (JSONObject) o;
        String key = jsonLineItem.getString("key");
        String value = jsonLineItem.getString("value");
        ...
    }
```

Works great... :)

Comment: This doesn't work for me, since a `JSONArray` is not iterable.

Comment: [org.json.JSONArray](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html) is not iterable, but [net.sf.json.JSONArray](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/JSONArray.html) is Iterable

Comment: your link is broken

Comment: this solution will not work

Answer (score 4):

Java 8 is in the market after almost 2 decades, following is the way to iterate `org.json.JSONArray` with java8 Stream API.

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

@Test
public void access_org_JsonArray() {
    //Given: array
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(new JSONObject(
                    new HashMap() {{
                        put("a", 100);
                        put("b", 200);
                    }}
            ),
            new JSONObject(
                    new HashMap() {{
                        put("a", 300);
                        put("b", 400);
                    }}
            )));

    //Then: convert to List<JSONObject>
    List<JSONObject> jsonItems = IntStream.range(0, jsonArray.length())
            .mapToObj(index -> (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(index))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // you can access the array elements now
    jsonItems.forEach(arrayElement -> System.out.println(arrayElement.get("a")));
    // prints 100, 300
}
```

If the iteration is only one time, (no need to `.collect`)

```
    IntStream.range(0, jsonArray.length())
            .mapToObj(index -> (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(index))
            .forEach(item -> {
               System.out.println(item);
            });
```

Comment: `.mapToObj` shows "unhandled exception: JSONException"

Comment: in syntax `.mapToObj(index -> (JSONObject) array.get(index))`, theres `jsonArray.get(index)` which potentially can throw `JSONException` but `JSONException extends RuntimeException` so it should fine at least at compile time

Answer (score 2):

By looking at your code, I sense you are using JSONLIB. If that was the case, look at the following snippet to convert json array to java array..

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) JSONSerializer.toJSON( input );  
 JsonConfig jsonConfig = new JsonConfig();  
 jsonConfig.setArrayMode( JsonConfig.MODE_OBJECT_ARRAY );  
 jsonConfig.setRootClass( Integer.TYPE );  
 int[] output = (int[]) JSONSerializer.toJava( jsonArray, jsonConfig );
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone else, 
I was able to convert to an array by doing something like this,

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(jsonString);
((JSONArray) jsonObject).toArray()
```

...or you should be able to get the length

```
((JSONArray) myJsonArray).toArray().length
```

Comment: `org.json.JSONObject` has a `toJSONArray(JSONArray names)` method and `org.json.JSONArray` has a `toJSONObject(JSONArray names)` method but it does not have a `toArray()` method.

Answer (score -2):

HashMap regs = (HashMap) parser.parse(stringjson);

(String)((**HashMap**)regs.get("firstlevelkey")).get("secondlevelkey");

Comment: A bit more clarification why your answer is better then the current accepted one would help understanding your solution.