# Is it possible to iterate through JSONArray?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [JSON Array iteration in Android/Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408985/json-array-iteration-in-android-java)
>   [JSONArray with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568762/jsonarray-with-java)

Is it possible to iterate through [JSONArray](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html) object using Iterator?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408985/json-array-iteration-in-android-java

Comment: The link on the question returns error 404.

Answer (score 286):

Not with an iterator.

For `org.json.JSONArray`, you can do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
  arr.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

For `javax.json.JsonArray`, you can do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
  arr.getJsonObject(i);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it will calling arr.length() on each iteration? So maybe better to put that into vairable and use that in the loop.

Comment: Well yes but it will be the same value everytime, but yes its unecessary a variable should be better.

Comment: Depends on the Compiler, Also I believe it'll just be a getter fetching a value which is not mutable from outside the instance, setting a variable would just allocate more memory 8-).

Comment: There is no `.length()` method on a `JsonArray`, but there is a `.size()` method inherited from `java.util.List`. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html

Comment: Is he referring to https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONArray.java?

Comment: Good Job......!!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `opt(int)` method and use a classical `for` loop.