# How to Iterate array of primitives in JSONata

Tags: java, arrays, iteration, nashorn, jsonata

I would like to know how to iterate an array of primitives such as array of int or if it is as a simple array of string.

```
{
   "printers":[
      "HP-1234",
      "HP-Inkjet"
   ]
}
```

I would like to iterate the array and do some thing like this:

```
for( String obj:printers) {
    if(obj.contains("HP")) {
        //do something here
    }
}
```

How can i do this using JSONata?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What is the exact data type of `printers`? `org.json.JSONArray`? `javax.json.JsonArray`? Something else?

Comment: printers will be org.json.JSONArray

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784874/is-it-possible-to-iterate-through-jsonarray

Comment: I would like to iterate it through JSONata as I am using the jsonata.js for querying the json scripts

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the solution which is as follows:

```
$map(printers, function($v, $i, $a) {
    $v~>$string()~>$contains("HP")?"HP Priter":$v
})
```

But since Am invoking the jasonata.js through Nashorn using java,
I am not able to get the proper result.

This is what i have done:

```
        Object resultjson = inv.invokeMethod(expr, "evaluate", inputjson);        
        engine.put("resultjson", resultjson);
        Object result = engine.eval("JSON.stringify(resultjson);");
        System.out.println("Result:" + result);
```

The output am getting is Result: [object Object]
Looking out for pointers to get the result in json format.

Note: I am using jsonata-es5.js as it is compatible with Nashorn

Comment: The expression `printers.($contains("HP") ? "HP-Printer" : $)` will do the same.  Note that the dot `.` operator is an implicit map function.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew ! This helps. I have a question. Not on this expression but on another expression. Is it possible to convert a string which has a number to number using JSONata? For this JSON "printerId":"0000" when i try printerId~>$number() i get cannot convert a value to number. I understand this is because am trying to convert a string to number, but if i want to do is it possible?

Comment: Ah right, `$number()` doesn't tolerate the leading zeros.  Raise an issue on GitHub - this could almost certainly be fixed.