# how to parse the array of json string using gson in android

Tags: android

```
{
   "serviceType":"IMAGE_ANDROID",
   "parameters":[
      [
         {
            "itemId":"it003376",
            "itemNameInEng":"8th Chennai International Film Festival Photos",
            "itemSmallImage":"http://122.183.217.134:8080/sivajitv/photos/20101216001017.jpg",
            "count":"110"
         },
         {
            "itemId":"it003375",
            "itemNameInEng":"Actress Aishwarya Rai Special Photos",
            "itemSmallImage":"http://122.183.217.134:8080/sivajitv/photos/20101215230917.jpg",
            "count":"7"
         },
         {
            "itemId":"it003374",
            "itemNameInEng":"Actor Srikanth Flag off The Avon Greenathon Bicycle Rally ",
            "itemSmallImage":"http://122.183.217.134:8080/sivajitv/photos/20101215212620.jpg",
            "count":"43"
         },
         {
            "itemId":"it003373",
            "itemNameInEng":"Kadamai Kanniyam Kattupadu Movie Launch Photos",
            "itemSmallImage":"http://122.183.217.134:8080/sivajitv/photos/20101213001908.jpg",
            "count":"32"
         },
         {
            "itemId":"it003372",
            "itemNameInEng":"Kanden Audio Launch Photos",
            "itemSmallImage":"http://122.183.217.134:8080/sivajitv/photos/20101210044334.jpg",
            "count":"126"
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

this is my response

i want to parse the parameters from this response and i need to parse all data in parameter

please provide me correct solution

Answer (score 0):

Make use of JSONArray class in org.json.JSONArray..

see this link

[Accessing members of items in a JSONArray with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568762/jsonarray-with-java)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [org.json](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) classes in the SDK.