# how to get JSONArray from http Url and how to set JSONArray to spinner in android?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-spinner, arrays

I have JSONArray ["category_1","category_2","category_3"] and I don't get data.
And how I set this data to spinner or listview in Android.

E:

where are faults?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String urlCat = "http://tvapp.pcrevue.sk/categories.json";

    Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray;
            jsonArray = getJSONArrayFromUrl(urlCat);

            final String[] array_spinner = new String[jsonArray.length()];

            //int show_total = jsonArray.length();

            //Toast.makeText(flash_tattoo.this, show_total + "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
            {
                String styleValue = jsonArray.getJSONArray(0).getString(i);
                array_spinner[i] = styleValue;

            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,array_spinner);

            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.activity_main);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public JSONArray getJSONArrayFromUrl(String url) {
        InputStream is = null;
        JSONArray jObj = null;
        String json = "";
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                //json += line;
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONArray(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Comment: for json array look at [this][1] may help


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568762/accessing-members-of-items-in-a-jsonarray-with-java

Answer (score 1):

You will need to parse the Json into objects.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308554/simplest-way-to-read-json-from-a-url-in-java) are some ways to do that.  Then you will need to create an ArrayListAdapter and populate it with an arraylist, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784081/android-create-spinner-programmatically-from-array).  That's it.

Edit:
For creating a JsonArray instead, see here for giving a string to the JSONArray constructor.

Comment: I don't have JSONObject but I have JSONArray.
Look at http://tvapp.pcrevue.sk/categories.json

Comment: Please do could you write example code.
I don't know imagine.