# Iterate through javax.json.JsonArray

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee

I have a `JsonArray` and I am using the implementation as given in [Java EE 7](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=353). How do I iterate thorugh this `JsonArray`?

I have searched thorugh this site but have found only answer which relate to `org.json.JSONArray` (like this [Accessing members of items in a JSONArray with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568762/accessing-members-of-items-in-a-jsonarray-with-java)) which I cannot use as `javax.json.JsonArray` does not have the length method.

Comment: Oh.. It does have size(). I overlooked that. Thanks.

Comment: Copied to answer with code sample

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking to [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html) will show that it extends `List`, so you can iterate with for loop:

```
javax.json.JsonArray value = javax.json.Json.createArrayBuilder()
     .add(javax.json.Json.createObjectBuilder()
             .add("type", "home")
             .add("number", "212 555-1234"))
     .add(javax.json.Json.createObjectBuilder()
             .add("type", "fax")
             .add("number", "646 555-4567"))
     .build();

for (javax.json.JsonValue jsonValue : value) {
    System.out.println(jsonValue);
}
```