# how to access json array element in java

Tags: java, json, rest

i am getting json array in the output.i want to access the specific key elments from the response .how can i ..?

```
 ResponseEntity <String> respone;
      try {
          response =
      restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);



      String response=response.getBody(); 
      JSONObject res = new JSONObject();
      res.put("result", response);
      System.out.println(res);
      int len=res.size();
      System.out.println(len);
      JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(response);
        JSONArray array = (JSONArray)obj;
        System.out.println(array.get(0)); }
```

this is respponse format i m getting in output.i want to access the bid from the response.how can i?

```
  [
      {
            "bName": "abc", 
            "bId": "n86nbnhbnghgy76"

          }
        ]
```

Comment: jackson? gson? libraries that help you parse pretty easily through elements

Comment: @sfat ... i am using jackson..

Comment: you're using JSONParser. If you have jackson in your project, just do a ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); AClassThatMatchesTheModelOfThatJson thatModel = mapper.readValue(response, AClassThatMatchesTheModelOfThatJson.class);

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing members of items in a JSONArray with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568762/accessing-members-of-items-in-a-jsonarray-with-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Try following:

```
  String response=response.getBody(); 
  JSONObject res = new JSONObject();
  System.out.println(res);
  int len=res.size();
  System.out.println(len);
  JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
    Object obj = parser.parse(response);
    JSONArray array = (JSONArray)obj;
    res=(JSONObject)array.get(0);
    System.out.println(res.get("bId"));
```

**Output :**

```
n86nbnhbnghgy76
```

This one is based on your code and with `Simple Json Library`.

Comment: .still same error - The constructor JSONArray(String) is undefined

Comment: Note `JSONArray.fromObject(response);` is what youshould use look at second line.

Comment: ..it showing this error- The method fromObject(String) is undefined for the type  JSONArray

Comment: Download json library from http://sourceforge.net/projects/json-lib/ link. You'll be good to go.

Comment: i have added import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;this class.but still same error.

Comment: I have edited my post look at the update. This surely would solve your doubts.

Answer (score 2):

Decode your string using `JSONArray(String json)` constructor:

```
String response = response.getBody(); 
JSONArray res = new JSONArray(response);
String bId = res.getJSONObject(0).get("bId");
System.out.println(bid);
```

Comment: it showing me error like this - The constructor JSONArray(String) is undefined for this line JSONArray res = new JSONArray(response);

Comment: ...i am using google json library.how can i slove the above error?

Comment: I don't use this implementation.