# Example to find a value in a list using common expression language (CEL)

Tags: expression, dynamic-execution, common-expression-language

I was following google common expression language specification, can some one guide me if i could do something like this:

I need to write an expression to find if "345" is in the phone_numbers list using google CEL .

```
json :  {"phone_numbers": ["123","234","345"] }

example :  phone_numbers.exist_one("345"); // this does not works ....
```

https://github.com/google/cel-spec/blob/master/doc/langdef.md#standard-definitions

Comment: you can directly access json values- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26095266/8098322

Answer (score 2):

I got the expression :

`phone_numbers.exists_one(r, r=="345")`

Answer (score 2):

Since you're just testing for the existence of a single value in a list, I would recommend using the `in` operator:

```
'345' in phone_numbers
```

The `exists_one` macro is pretty useful if `'345'` can only appear exactly once in the list.