# Convert returned JSON String to a JSONArray

Tags: java, json, web-services

I have a web service that performs a database query, converts the result set to a JSON String and returns the strung to the client. This is the code for the converter (I got it from http://biercoff.com/nice-and-simple-converter-of-java-resultset-into-jsonarray-or-xml/):

```
public static String convertToJSON(ResultSet resultSet)
        throws Exception {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        int total_rows = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        for (int i = 0; i < total_rows; i++) {
            obj.put(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i + 1)
                    .toLowerCase(), resultSet.getObject(i + 1));
        }
        jsonArray.add(obj);
    }
    return jsonArray.toJSONString();
}
```

In the client application when I print the returned string it is in the following format:

```
[{"Column1":0.333333,"Column2":"FirmA"},{"Column1":0.666667,"Column2":"FirmB"}]
```

so far all is good. The problem I am having is converting the returned string into a JSON array. I tried this:

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(JSON_STRING);
```

but got the following error message: constructor JSONArray in class JSONArray cannot be applied to given types. I tried to first convert in into a JSON object like so:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
```

but got the following error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Map. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: See syntax of a json array http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp, the returned string should be in this format arr: [{}, {}]

Comment: This is the format of the returned string that I have shown above. I don't see any discrepancy.

Comment: You are missing "arr":, instead its just the array value in your string.

Comment: Please change "total_rows" to "total_columns".

Comment: 6ton I have produced the string in the form: {"Chart":[{"Column1":0.333333,"Column2":"FirmA"} ,{"Column1":0.666667,"Column2":"FirmB"}]} but Im still having the exact problems.

Comment: Kindly share which json library you are using with version number. This seems to be the issue of the version of library that you are using.

Comment: I was using the json-simple-1.1.1.jar file. I changed it to java-json.ajr which I got from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm and the code worked.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem was with the json library that I was using. Once I used the

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
```

it all worked out well. I was able to convert the returned string to an array using

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(JSON_STRING);
```

and to iterate through the values I used the code provided in this answer: [Accessing members of items in a JSONArray with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568762/accessing-members-of-items-in-a-jsonarray-with-java/1568815#1568815) which I reproduce here for simplicity:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); ++i) {
    JSONObject rec = arr.getJSONObject(i);
    int id = rec.getInt("id");
    String loc = rec.getString("loc");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I think that will not be correct with the String because string can be anything u need to convert an array to string.

Comment: The method posted in the question returns an array which is converted to a string. When I changed the json library I was using I was able to create an array from the string on the client side. The jar which worked for me came from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm

Answer (score 0):

well you need to do it by this way for example

```
String jsonText = "[0,{\"1\":{\"2\":{\"3\":{\"4\":[5,{\"6\":7}]}}}}]";
        try {

            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonText);
            System.out.println(array);
            System.out.println(array.length());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the correct library used. The mess is that [org.json.simple](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.json%22%20AND%20a%3A%22json%22) is often suggested by IDE as default for **JSONObject** and **JSONArray**.

You can find a link to latest jar for org.json library above.