# get number of value from json array java

Tags: java, json, converters

Help me please. I have a json data:

JSON OBJECT

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "parentId": 0,
    "bookableResourceId": "046d375d-6240-31e9-acea-c7fd54637608",
    "userId": "4bda1135-2e49-379c-b086-cd082c50eb34",
    "eventId": null,
    "title": "Jaskolski-Ledner",
    "description": "Laudantium fuga et aut voluptas aut est officiis. Distinctio sint iste velit dolor consectetur. Quod et deleniti fugiat. Voluptatum fugiat eum ut ab est.",
    "attendees": [],
    "reminder": 15,
    "rrule": null,
    "exdate": null,
    "checkedIn": true,
    "dateFrom": "2015-02-01T12:00:00Z",
    "dateTo": "2015-02-01T13:30:00Z",
    "dateCreated": "2015-03-19T06:55:35Z",
    "dateUpdated": "2015-03-19T06:55:35Z"
 },
{
        "id": 4,
        "parentId": 0,
        "bookableResourceId": "05162c53-5d9e-3b2a-a578-0789f7adf79e",
        "userId": "60e33324-b609-33fa-bfde-04571c72db58",
        "eventId": null,
        "title": "Barton, Shields and Grady",
        "description": "Quia nobis aut aliquid doloremque. Sit cupiditate itaque totam pariatur commodi. Voluptatem omnis ducimus est mollitia.",
        "attendees": [],
        "reminder": 15,
        "rrule": null,
        "exdate": null,
        "checkedIn": false,
        "dateFrom": "2015-02-01T12:00:00Z",
        "dateTo": "2015-02-01T13:30:00Z",
        "dateCreated": "2015-03-19T06:55:35Z",
        "dateUpdated": "2015-03-19T06:55:35Z"
  }
```

I need calculate value in json (How much value in all array). How can I do 
it?

Comment: in what platform? java or javascript? or something else?

Comment: which value do you want to calculate ? You will need a JSON Parser in order to accomplish your task.

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568762/accessing-members-of-items-in-a-jsonarray-with-java

you can get json in array and count array length

Comment: first off, thats not valid Json. secondly: what does "(How much value in all array)." mean?