# creating JsonObject from JSONArray value in JAVA

Tags: java, json

I have a JsonArray Object like

```
             JsonArray[0]= { "streetName" : "xyz", "wardName" : "12xz"}
             JsonArray[1]= { "doorNumber" : "123", "plot" : "90z"}
             JsonArray[2]= { "city" : "pqr", "district" : "nmc"}
             JsonArray[3]= { "state" : "hisd", "country" : "kasps"}
```

I want to convert above JsonArray into JsonObject which will be like

```
{
    "addresss":[ {
        "streetName": "xyz",
        "wardName": "12xz",
        "doorNumber": "123",
        "plot": "90z",
        "city": "pqr",
        "district": "nmc",
        "state": "hisd",
        "country": "kasps"
    }]
}
```

I tried in different ways using Json Objcet put and traversing JSONarray and appending the value to String builder. No use. any one give me some idea. how to do that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: what you have is not a jsonarray but an array of json objects

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10593838/2310289

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing members of items in a JSONArray with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568762/accessing-members-of-items-in-a-jsonarray-with-java)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your replay. can you check now, I want the Json Object like that

Comment: Thank you Jobin, but in this array of Json objects have different keys with different values

Comment: StringBuilder usually works for this kind of situation....What error or difficulties are you having when using `StringBuilder`

Comment: HI Nirmal Raj, Thank you for your reply. I tried with String Builder. while appending { } also appending. like "addresss":[ {
        "streetName": "xyz",
        "wardName": "12xz"}
       { "doorNumber": "123",
        "plot": "90z"}
        {"city": "pqr",
        "district": "nmc"}
        {"state": "hisd",
        "country": "kasps"}
    }]