# Get all values for a field from nested java object

Tags: java, reflection, java-8

I have a Java object as shown below. I need to iterate through this nested object and fetch all values for one field. Ex 'time' for below java object.

If it is a list, I can use java 8 filters. But how to do this on an object?

Also, I need to do it in a generic way.

```
    {
  "dataType": "Node",
  "totalCount": 1,
  "count": 1,
  "startIndex": 0,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "a4b7a825f67930965747445709011120-Node-6f638b5e71debd5807ec7fb73b9dc20b",
      "refObjects": {},
      "tid": "a4b7a825f67930965747445709011120",
      "creationDate": "2018-09-20T06:55:36.742+0000",
      "lmd": "2018-09-20T06:55:36.799+0000",
      "exceptions": [
        {
          "name": "projectedInventory",
          "status": "Stockout",
          "severity": "High",
          "time": "2018-09-20T00:00:00.000+0000"
        }
      ],
      "criticalities": [
        "HotItem"
      ],
      "customerName": "Best Buys",
      "supplierName": "Samsung",
      "customerItemName": "Ship to item name",
      "nodeType": "inventory",
      "supplierItemName": "Ship from item name",
      "shipToSiteName": "IT06",
      "shipFromSiteName": "IT07",
      "status": "Active",
      "lob": "HC",
      "processType": "demandSupply",
      "measures": {
        "maxInventory": [
          {
            "refObjects": {},
            "time": "2018-09-26T00:00:00.000+0000",
            "quantity": 0
          },
          {
            "refObjects": {},
            "time": "2018-09-27T00:00:00.000+0000",
            "quantity": 0
          }
        ],
        "maxDistribution": [
          {
            "refObjects": {},
            "time": "2018-09-28T00:00:00.000+0000",
            "quantity": 0
          },
          {
            "refObjects": {},
            "time": "2018-09-29T00:00:00.000+0000",
            "quantity": 0
          },
          {
            "refObjects": {},
            "time": "2018-09-30T00:00:00.000+0000",
            "quantity": 0
          },
          {
            "refObjects": {},
            "time": "2018-10-07T00:00:00.000+0000",
            "quantity": 0
          },
          {
            "refObjects": {},
            "time": "2018-10-14T00:00:00.000+0000",
            "quantity": 0
          },
          {
            "refObjects": {},
            "time": "2018-10-21T00:00:00.000+0000",
            "quantity": 0
          },
          {
            "refObjects": {},
            "time": "2018-10-28T00:00:00.000+0000",
            "quantity": 0
          },
          {
            "refObjects": {},
            "time": "2018-11-04T00:00:00.000+0000",
            "quantity": 0
          },
          {
            "refObjects": {},
            "time": "2018-11-25T00:00:00.000+0000",
            "quantity": 0
          }
        ]
      },
      "customerItemDescription": "EXP08CN1W6  PORTABLE AIR CONDITIONER HC",
      "materialGroup": "ELX",
      "shipToSiteDescription": "IT - BE10 Porcia Hub"
    }
  ],
  "typeCounts": null
}
```

Now I want to retrieve all the values of "time" field and save it in a list. What's the best approach to do this?

The output should be something like this:

```
{
  "time": [
    "2018-12-30T00:00:00.000+0000",
    "2018-08-24T12:00:00.000+0000"
  ]
}
```

Comment: and what did you try?

Comment: I tried using reflection but was not able to do it for nested objects.

Comment: Please share what you've tried so that people can help you with what you can improve.

Comment: You need a JSON Reader, fetch all fields for "time", and iterate over the results. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568762/accessing-members-of-items-in-a-jsonarray-with-java

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection also ,but apache-commons makes it easier. the method that I have written below takes two argument one is your POJO object and another one is empty list.and it will return the same list by populating all the value of property `"time"` in your input object even if there are nested object. in `else if` I have added one condition where I am checking if className contains "com.your.packageName" or not, this is because here I am assuming that all your POJO(which can be nested in your input object) are stored in a package "com.your.packageName" so if you have your all POJOs stored at one location then you replace it with your package name.
Add following dependency for the common-beanutills.

```
 <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
 <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
 <version>1.9.2</version>
```

---

```
    import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanMap;
    import org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean;

     private static List<String> getPropertyValue(Object myObj, List<String> timeList) {
            final BeanMap beanMap = new BeanMap(myObj);
            PropertyUtilsBean pp = new PropertyUtilsBean();
            beanMap.keySet().stream().forEach(x -> {
                try {
                     String propertyName= ""+x;
                     //GET THE CLASS TYPE OF PROPERTY
                     String proprtyTypeClassName=""+pp.getPropertyType((Object)myObj,propertyName);
                     System.out.println(propertyName+"  "+proprtyTypeClassName);
                     if(propertyName.equals("time")) {
                         //GET THE VALUE OF A propertyName FROM object myObj
                         timeList.add((String)pp.getProperty(myObj, propertyName));
                     }
                     else if(proprtyTypeClassName.contains("com.your.packageName")) {
//recursively call same method if value is another POJO object nested inside
                         getPropertyValue(pp.getProperty(myObj, propertyName),timeList);
                     }
                } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            return timeList;
        }
```

let me know in case you have any doubt.

Comment: Hi Nawnit. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much. I was trying some solutions and found one below. Let me know if this also looks correct:

```
package com.company.dct.exec.lib.relationships.util;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import java.util.Map;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("objectPathValuesExtractor")
public class ObjectPathValuesExtractor {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ObjectPathValuesExtractor.class);

    /**
     * Extract values for a given path from current object.
     *
     * @param object the object
     */

    public <T extends Object> T extractValues(Object object, String pathExpression) {
        T values = null;
        if (object == null) {
            return values;
        }
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.setDefaultPropertyInclusion(JsonInclude.Value.construct(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS, JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL));
            Map<String, Object> mappedObject = mapper.convertValue(object, Map.class);
            values = JsonPath.read(mappedObject, pathExpression);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Failed to load alert referenced object.", e);
        }
        return values;
    }
}
```

Here I am using
`compile group: 'com.jayway.jsonpath', name: 'json-path', version: '2.4.0'` 
from apache

And then i'm calling this function

`List<Map<String, Extensible>> refObjects = objectPathValuesExtractor.extractValues(object, "$..time");`