# get JSONObject from JSONArray

Tags: java, arrays, json, org.json

```
for(int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++){
            JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
            Resources.show(jo);
}
```

In the above code I want to fetch the json object from json array. But I'm getting an error

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONArray[0] is not a JSONObject.
at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:343)
at webutilities.Try.main(JSON.java:50)
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

What else are the methods to fetch a json object from json array.

Comment: Could you also share what your JSONArray looks like? Seems like you did not store a JSONObject in index zero judging from your exception

Comment: Can you please share the whole code?

Comment: In your example you show an individual element of the array, what type are the elements?  The array itself is already a JSON object.

Comment: Refer to the post for clarification.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568762/accessing-members-of-items-in-a-jsonarray-with-java)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
System.out.println(ja.get(i).getClass().toString());
```

to find out what kind of object is within your JSONArray.

E.g. if you have Strings in there, simply use:

```
ja.getString(i)
```