# Need to read a JSON array object using java

Tags: java, json

Need to iterate the json array object using java please some guid me on this

I have posed my JSON structure 
Below are the json given by developer i need to get  the json array object as a input for my selenium script.

Can some one please help me on this?

```
[{
        "Name": "Name1",
        "Address": "Address",
        "PhoneNo": 2142751,
        "Courses": [{
                "CourseName": "JAVA",
                "Cost": 12000
            },
            {
                "CourseName": "Testing",
                "Cost": 12000
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "Name2",
        "Address": "Address2",
        "PhoneNo": 214275143,

        "Courses": [{
                "CourseName": "JAVAV2",
                "Cost": 12000
            },
            {
                "CourseName": "Security",
                "Cost": 12000
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Expected 
String name = value of Name
String courseName = value of CourseName

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing members of items in a JSONArray with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568762/accessing-members-of-items-in-a-jsonarray-with-java)

Answer (score 0):

Well, here we just import the class ObjectMapper, than of course, whe have to instantiate it in the class we need.
After that, call the function:

```
Object object = objectMapper.readValue(jsonAsString, Object.class);
```

Maybe that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options to read a JSON, you can use JSONArray from primefaces library or JsonArray from google library.

In this case im using `import org.primefaces.json.JSONArray;`
Be sure to have that library or jar, or dependency if using maven.

To get name and courseName do as follow:

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(yourJsonStringGoesHere);
String name = jArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("Name");
String courseName = jArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("Courses").getJSONObject(0).getString("CourseName");
```

Also, if you need to get every single name and courseName from the JSON you can do a for loop like this:

```
            // JSONArray made with your JSON String
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(yourJsonString);
            // JSONArray made with the sub array of courses in your JSON
            JSONArray jArrayCourses = jArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("Courses");
            // Loop trough your JSON array
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                // Get name of each JSONObject inside your array
                String name = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Name");
                System.out.println("name: "+name);
                // Loop trough each sub array of courses.
                for (int j = 0; j < jArrayCourses.length(); j++) {
                    // Get courseName of each JSONObject inside your courses sub array
                    String courseName = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("Courses").getJSONObject(j)
                            .getString("CourseName");
                    System.out.println("courseName: "+courseName);

                }

            }
```

**Output**

```
name: Name1
courseName: JAVA
courseName: Testing
name: Name2
courseName: JAVAV2
courseName: Security
```

Ask me if you don't understand something or need more help im feeling generous today :)

Comment: @Bhanu you are welcome :) don't forget to pinch the green thingy please