# Parse a String java

Tags: java, arrays, json, list, hdfs

I have a `BuilderString` that contain the same result as in this link:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/

I'm looking to extract the values of the ``. And return a list of String that contain all the files name.

My code is:

```java
try {
    HttpURLConnection conHttp = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conHttp.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conHttp.setDoInput(true);

    InputStream in = conHttp.getInputStream();
    int ch;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How can I parse JSON to take all the values of `pathSuffix` and return a `list of string` that contains the file names ?
Could you please give me a suggestion ? Thanks

Comment: That's not really a String, that's JSON. Parsing JSON and parsing a String are a bit different.

Comment: You need to use some json library. E.g. gson or jackson

Comment: Yes its a JSON. I have the same output as in the link. But, I converted it to a String trying to find a solution to parse it :) 
Assuming I have a JSON. In my code until  String response = sb.toString(); How can I parse it the JSON to extract the value of pathSuffix ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***The good option***

Do the following steps:

1. [Convert to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-jsonstring-to-jsonobject-in-java)
2. Get the value using: `JSONObject.get("FileStatuses").getAsJson().get("FileStatus").getAsJsonArray()`
3. [Iterate over all objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568762/accessing-members-of-items-in-a-jsonarray-with-java) in the array to get the value you want

***The bad option***

Although as mentioned it is not recommended- If you want to stay with Strings you can use:

```
String str_to_find= "pathSuffix"      : \"";

while (str.indexOf(str_to_find) != -1){
   str = str.substring(str.indexOf(str_to_find)+str_to_find.length);
   value = str.substring(0,str.indexOf("\""));
   System.out.println("Value is " + value);
}
```

Comment: which language you used ?

Comment: Its java, like the title mentioned.

Comment: it seems quasi java, . For example the first line its not java. I didn't understand your solution. In fact, what I'm looking is to parse the JSON that in the StringBuilder (sb), take all the value of pathSuffix and return a list of String that contain the file names.

Comment: Here, I added String before. Now its java. I manipulated the String (str) for you. Please edit your message to be something like: " How can I parse JSON to take all the values of pathSuffex and return a list of string that contains the file names ? " , and we'll answer it for you :)

Comment: Do you have an idea please ?

Answer (score 2):

That is JSON formatted data; JSON is not regular, tehrefore, trying to parse this with a regular expression is impossible, and trying to parse it out with substring and friends will take you a week and will be very error prone.

Read up on what [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) is (no worries; it's very simple to understand!), then get a *good* JSON library (the standard json.org library absolutely sucks, don't get that one), such as [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson), and the code to extract what you need will be robust and easy to write and test.

Comment: Could you please propose me a solution ? I would like to extract the value of the pathSuffix  and return a List of String that contain all the files names. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes; add Jackson to your dependencies list, read up on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to build from scratch an API binding for hadoop.
This binding exist already for the Java language:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#listLocatedStatus-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-org.apache.hadoop.fs.PathFilter-

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use any dependencies from Hadoop