# How to Loop through an object array and retrieve a specific item in Java without using JSONArray

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am receiving the JSONArray below,

```
[
    {
        "test": "Nivea Men",
        "category": null,
        "stock": null,
        "promoBundle": true,
        "discountPrice": 12.5
    },
    {
        "test": "Vaseline",
        "category": null,
        "stock": null,
        "promoBundle": true,
        "discountPrice": 12.5
    },
    {
        "test": "Blueband",
        "category": null,
        "stock": null,
        "promoBundle": true,
        "discountPrice": 12.5
    }
]
```

How can I extract a single object like `discountPrice` and introduce it to a if statement to check if is null or not and perform some logic.

I know the way how to loop through a list of items and add them to an array like. And also extract a single String value and map it to an `AtomicReference`

```
AtomicReference<String> territory = new AtomicReference<>("");
List <String> itemData = new ArrayList<>();
cart.getItems().forEach(pt -> {
  itemData.add(pt.getItemId());
  territory.set(pt.getTerritory());
});
```

but how can I extract only a single value of type double without adding it to an array list?. Any help is appreciated.
I have tried tried

```
  AtomicReference<Double> discountPrice  = new AtomicReference<>((double) 0);
    listItems.forEach(dc->{
      discountPRice.set(dc.getDiscountPrice());
    });
```

Passing the discountPrice after extracting it

```
 cart.getItems().forEach(
      cartItem -> {
          CreateOrderDto.ItemDto item = CreateOrderDto.ItemDto();
          item.setDiscountPrice(discountPrice);

        }
```

but whenever I try to access the discount amount from somewhere else it prompts me to Change 1st parameter of method `setDiscountPrice` from `Double` to `AtomicReference<Double>`, and I don't want to change it I want it to remain as `double`. Any help is appreciated

Comment: You're asking about a problem calling `setDiscountAmount`, but you haven't shown the code that is calling it.

Comment: You also haven't shown the type of `listItems`, or explained which item you want from the array (your loop always gets the last value).

Comment: Hi @tgdavies I have updated, I want to extract the `discountPrice`

Comment: maybe this answer in another topic will help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1568815/14577421