# How to compare two ArrayList and output value

Tags: java, json, arraylist, hashmap, org.json

Without using GSON.

I'm attempting to pull the text value from the 'chores' array if there is a matching value in 'chore' array within myFilterObj object.

```json
{
    "chores": [
        {
            "text": "Wash the car",
            "value": 1
        },
        {
            "text": "Mow the lawn",
            "value": 2
        },
        {
            "text": "Vaccumm the floor",
            "value": 3
        },
        {
            "text": "Walk the dog",
            "value": 4
        }
    ],
    "myFilterObj": {
        "chore": [
            1,
            2
        ]
    }
}
```

The first thing I did was convert them to ArrayLists.

Below are the two ArrayLists.  My goal is to printout the text from first ArrayList if that value is in the second ArrayList.

For Example: Wash the car and Vaccumm the floor should printout since 1 and 2 are in the second ArrayList and 1 and 2 are values in the first ArrayList.

Here is what I have so far.  I'm stuck on trying to do the comparison for allChores.value to value.  I think I should be using removeAll or contains??

```
JSONArray allChores = data.getJSONArray("chores");
JSONArray myChores = myFilterObj.getJSONArray("chore"); 
ArrayList<Object> listdata1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
ArrayList<Object> listdata2 = new ArrayList<Object>();
if (allChores != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < allChores.length(); i++) {
        //Adding each element of JSON array into ArrayList
        listdata1.add(allChores.get(i));
    }
}
if (myChores != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < myChores.length(); i++) {
        //Adding each element of JSON array into ArrayList
        listdata2.add(myChores.get(i));
    }
}
//comapare allChores.value to myChores(value)
//printout allChores.text on match
```

```json
[ 
    {
        "text":"Wash the car",
        "value":1
    }, 
    {
        "text":"Mow the lawn",
        "value":7
    }, 
    {
        "text":"Vaccumm the floor",
        "value":2
    }, 
    {
        "text":"Walk the dog",
        "value":8
    }
]
[
    1,
    2,
    3
]
```

Comment: You've defined your Lists as generic Object but I suspect this should be JSONObject.  You may find this question useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1568762/7275056

Comment: Mow the Lawn is 7

Comment: @Arba. Cannot use GSON

Answer (score 0):

The following answer was composed under the assumption, that GSON can be used.

I would start by converting the input into POJOs. For that, I would introduce for every object in the input a separate record `Chore`, `McChores` and `Input` itself.

```java
record Chore(int value, String text) {
}

record MyChores(List<Integer> chore) {
}

record Input(List<Chore> chores, MyChores myFilterObj) {
}
```

Such that you can then create look up map of the chores

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final var data = """
            {
                "chores": [
                    {
                        "text": "Wash the car",
                        "value": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "Mow the lawn",
                        "value": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "Vaccumm the floor",
                        "value": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "Walk the dog",
                        "value": 4
                    }
                ],
                "myFilterObj": {
                    "chore": [
                        1,
                        2,
                        7
                    ]
                }
            }
            """;
    final var input = new Gson().fromJson(data, Input.class);
    final Map<Integer, String> choresLookup = input.chores().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Chore::value, Chore::text));
    final var myChores = input.myFilterObj().chore().stream()
            .filter(choresLookup::containsKey) // absent values gets filtered out
            .map(choresLookup::get)
            .toList();
}
```

Results in

```
[Wash the car, Mow the lawn]
```

Comment: Thank you Valerij but I can't use GSON

Comment: I'm using org.json.JSONArray maybe I should use Set or a Map

Comment: @JasperLearner I would use a Map. But a List would be pretty much as fast up until the order of hundred or even thousand entries in both collections.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit overkill but my preferred solution would be to create a lookup map for the chores and then iterate over the IDs to generate the labels.

```java
private static Map<Integer, String> makeLookupMap(JSONArray chores) {
    final var result = HashMap.newHashMap(chores.length()); // new since Java 19
    for (Object entry : chores) {
        JSONObject chore = (JSONObject) entry;
        int id = chore.getInt("value");
        String label = chore.getString("text");
        result.put(id, label);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then the processing of the input is more or less the same as my GSON solution but with more procedural processing because the JSONArrays is already an Iterable otherwise it would need to be converted twice (Iterable -> List -> Stream).

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final var data = ""/* as before */;
    final JSONObject input = new JSONObject(data);
    final JSONArray chores = input.getJSONArray("chores");
    final Map<Integer, String> choresLookup = makeLookupMap(chores);
    final List<String> myChores = new ArrayList<>();
    final var choreIds = input.getJSONObject("myFilterObj").getJSONArray("chore");
    for (Object choreId : choreIds) {
        final var id = (int) choreId;
        if (choresLookup.containsKey(id)) {
            myChores.add(choresLookup.get(id));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(myChores);
}
```

which also results in

```
[Wash the car, Mow the lawn]
```

Comment: Thanks Ill give it a shot. What's the 14/10?

Comment: He is trying to set the initial size of the map. Generally not advisable to do that, since that is implementation specific.

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer it is perfectly fine when the amount of max entries is known, like in this case.

Comment: And 14/10s is an optimistic inversion of the default load factor. But the Java 19 API `HashMap#newHashMap(capacity)` is better suited, because 14/10 can overflow.